# Get custom column name while doing pivot in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

data set:

```
CREATE TABLE bank (
    name varchar(255),
    val int,
    amount int
);

insert into bank values ('john',1,2000);
insert into bank values ('peter',1,1999);
insert into bank values ('peter',2,1854);
insert into bank values ('adi',1,1888);
```

Table Bank:

```
name  val   amount
--------------------   
John   1     2000    
Peter  1     1999    
Peter  2     1854    
adi    1     1888
```

pivoting using sum case:

```
SELECT name
    ,[1]
    ,[2]
FROM (
    SELECT name
        ,val
        ,amount
    FROM bank
    ) t
PIVOT(sum(amount) FOR Val IN (
            [1]
            ,[2]
            )) AS piv
```

output:

```
name    amountval1 amountval2
-----------------------------    
adi     1888       0    
john    2000       0    
peter   1999       1854
```

using pivot function:

```
select name ,[1],[2] from(
select name, val, amount from bank ) t
PIVOT (sum(amount) For Val in ([1],[2])) as piv
```

Output:

```
name    1       2
-----------------
adi     1888    NULL    
john    2000    NULL
peter   1999    1854
```

Now the problem is I want to get the custom name i.e. amountval1 instead of 1 as i have done while using sum case. Can anyone help me get custom column name using pivot function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a simple query and you don't need a `sub-query` or `CTE`:

just remember `Pivot` will rename the `From table` to `Pivot Table` `[e.g. Col]` :

```
select
    name,
    Col.[1] as amountval1,
    Col.[2] as amountval2
from bank
PIVOT (sum(amount) For Val in ([1],[2])) Col
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally recommend conditional aggregation in this case:

```
select name,
       sum(case when val = 1 then amount else 0 end) as amountval1,
       sum(case when val = 2 then amount else 0 end) as amountval2
from bank b
group by name;
```

This has several advantages in my opinion:

- It uses standard SQL syntax.
- It never requires a subquery -- even when `bank` has additional columns.
- You can control the aggregation logic, so `0` is returned rather than `NULL`.
- Renaming the columns is trivial.